# How to design access to files that can contain different types?

Tags: c++, types

We have an internally used type of file here that is basically a table where **columns can have different types**. There is also a header with IDs identifying which column is which type. Users typically do not generate table layouts all the time, there is rather a limited set of table layouts (say 10 or so, but more to come in the future).

My question is: **What is the best approach to model this file in C++?**

I can think of the following possibilities:

1. Create a templated file class where the **template parameter is a struct containing the types of the columns**.
   In a different, static template class, put the header IDs as a static member and provide a function for endianness-safe reading (via explicit template specialisation).

   Disadvantage: Need to create struct and static partner class for each file. Will fail at link time if static template class has no specialisation for this type. Is perhaps a misuse of templates.
2. Create an abstract data class, derive explicit overrides for each type that can be in a column and **dynamically cast** the pointers-to-base-class that I get from the file back to the right type (which I can find out via the header).

   Disadvantage: Dynamic cast on every read.
3. Create a templated file class as above. **Require from the template that it has methods** which read and write a file header and provide endianness-safe reading.

   Disadvantage: Need to create class with these methods for each file type instead of using plain structs as in 1. Require explicit template specialisations for built-in types.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since files are read-up at run-time, compile time solutions aren't real "solution".
This is a typical case for a "hierarchy of polymorphic classes" sharing a common root, destined to a collection of `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to `dynamic_cast` from.

basically, you guess the type from the data format, and `push_back` a `x_ptr<BaseClass>(new ActualClass)`.

`BaseClass` can hold a way to allow you to recognize which `ActualClass` you're dealing with, but that's noting more what `dynamic_cast` does. Just let `BaseClass` empty, with just a virtual destructor.

On the file, every record must start with a sort of "type_id" the actually tells you what is the actual type the following data represent.

Comment: I should add that, typically the person opening the file should know what kinds of types to accept. Otherwise, we would need to write a wrapper in cases 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Use self-descriptive data types ("type-size-value" triples), and perform cast per type.
2. Use XML structures (variation of the above, basically)
3. Use relative database (SQLite embedded in your code, for example, or anything else)